# Ecological simulation, how to compare multiple numbers in a matrix to make a decision

Tags: r, matrix

I have an issue that has come up during an ecological simulation I am developing.  I have attached some code below to highlight the issue.  In summary, let's say I have 3 locations of different quality.  The animal wants to move to the highest quality location (the higher the number, the higher the quality), but cannot differentiate between qualities that differ by less than or equal to 0.1 (this is part of a larger loop, so this process will get repeated thousands of times).

For example, in this case (where the individual starts in location #2):

```
a<-matrix(c(1,2,3,.6,.9,.7),nrow=2,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
attributes(a)$dimnames<-list(c("Location","Quality"),c())
a

          [,1] [,2] [,3]
Location  1.0  2.0  3.0
Quality   0.6  0.9  0.7
```

The individual would clearly discern location #2 as the best, and stay there.

In this case (where the individual starts in location #2):

```
a<-matrix(c(1,2,3,.5,.7,.8),nrow=2,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
attributes(a)$dimnames<-list(c("Location","Quality"),c())
a

          [,1] [,2] [,3]
Location  1.0  2.0  3.0
Quality   0.5  0.7  0.8
```

The individual would not be able to clearly discern between the quality of location #2 and #3 (because the difference needs to be at least 0.1 to be detected), and this would trigger an alternative behavior (which may involve the individual staying in #2, or evaluating more locations not present in this example). However, I would need to know that Location #2 and #3 are close in quality, while location #1 is eliminated as an option.

In this case (again, starting in location #2)

```
a<-matrix(c(1,2,3,.9,.7,.6),nrow=2,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
attributes(a)$dimnames<-list(c("Location","Quality"),c())
a
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
Location  1.0  2.0  3.0
Quality   0.9  0.7  0.6
```

The individual would move from location 2 to location 1.

In this case (again, starting in location #2)

```
a<-matrix(c(1,2,3,.8,.7,.6),nrow=2,ncol=3,byrow=TRUE)
attributes(a)$dimnames<-list(c("Location","Quality"),c())
a
         [,1] [,2] [,3]
Location  1.0  2.0  3.0
Quality   0.8  0.7  0.6
```

The individual would eliminate Location #3 based on its difference from Location #1, and would not be able to choose between staying in #2 or moving to #1

I am trying to figure out how to write a code that will compare the relative quality of the locations, and return to me if the individual cannot differentiate between locations (and if so, which ones is it choosing between), or if one location is clearly greater (and if so, it needs to return the location number so I can move the individual to that location in another matrix).

Comment: You need to be looking at http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html and learning how to create spatial-data.frames. Matrices are not a good choice for generalizing this task to two or more dimensions.

Comment: From the question, it's not clear if this is an explicitly spatial model. If the animal can evaluate and move to any cell in the landscape, their spatial arrangement doesn't matter. On the other hand, if animals are limited to evaluating and moving among adjacent cells, then location does matter. It would also be useful to know if the quality of each location changes, or if their rankings will remain the same throughout the simulation. It's hard to provide clear advice with just this snippet.

Comment: Tyler, thanks for the comment.  This is spatially explicit (20 locations for now, but that will potentially change), and the 'quality' measure is changing frequently as individuals move between habitats.  Individuals can only sample neighboring patches, and I have all issues with that well constructed.   I am at the point where I can identify the locations an individual is going to compare, and can pull out those locations and qualities in the above manner. Now that I have identified which patches the individual can compare, all I need to do is figure out a way to make the above decision

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a class for the Location. I don't know how you would go about doing that in r, but I'm sure you can figure that part out.

This is the algorithm I would suggest:

- For each location, for each other location, if the organism can tell the difference in quality, mark the lower-ranked one as 'bad' (maybe using a boolean array; do NOT use a flag inside the object for this, as that violates good design)
- In those for loops, use a continue statement if you grab a Location with the flag marked, to save time.
- Now, go through the list again, and copy to a new list all the ones that don't have the flag marked.
- Examine the length of the list and use that in the decision-making.